# Simulate javascript click on X,Y point (to be used to control a silverlight player)

Tags: javascript

I am looking to hack the netflix video player to jump to specific points using javascript. There doesn't seem to be any api that is accessible via javascript.

I was wondering if it was possible to simulate mouse clicks at x & y positions using javascript that would enable me to click on elements in the silverlight app. If I know video scrubber is at a specific position, can I simulate a click at that position?

Comment: Is there a reason this has to be done in JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simulate a click on a page element. But not a specific location. If you wrote the silverlight application, then you can make it able to [interact with JavaScript on the page](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/salvapatuel/archive/2008/05/01/build-interaction-between-javascript-and-silverlight-2.aspx). If you didn't write it then you're stuck.